# Pandas: Restucture a dataframe to column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe where the cities are columns and ages are the values:

| City1 | City2 | City3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 14 | 61 |
| 51 | 73 | 35 |
| 42 | 38 | 13 |
| 12 | 75 | 24 |
| 27 | 42 | 78 |

I want to create a new dataframe where the columns are age groups, and the cities are the index, like so:

|  | 0-20 | 20-40 | 40-60 | 60-80 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| City2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| City3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Is this possible to do in pandas?

Answer (score 6):

Try this, using `pd.cut`:

```
dfc = pd.cut(df.rename_axis('Cities', axis=1).stack(), 
             bins=[-np.inf,20,40,60,np.inf], 
             labels='0-20 20-40 40-60 60-80'.split(' ')).reset_index()

pd.crosstab(dfc['Cities'], dfc[0]).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
0 Cities  0-20  20-40  40-60  60-80
0  City1     2      1      2      0
1  City2     1      1      1      2
2  City3     1      2      0      2
```

Comment: Sweet solution mate

Comment: @Umar.H Thank you.

Comment: Slightly more compact version with `apply`: `df.apply(pd.cut, axis=0, bins=[0,20,40,60,80]).apply(pd.Series.value_counts).T`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for all combinations of the range and the citys.

```
new_data = []
for city in df.columns:
    new_city = []
    for left, right in [(0,20),(20,40),(40,60),(60,80)]:
        new_city.append(df[city].between(left,right, inclusive="left").sum())
    new_data.append(new_city)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=["0-20","20-40","40-60","60-80"], index=[df.columns])
new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#this should work

import pandas as pd

#creating df
data = [[2, 14, 61], [51, 73, 35], [42, 38, 13], [12, 75, 24], [27, 42, 78]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['city1', 'city2', 'city3'])

#sorting by given intervals

data_new = [[df[(df['city1'] > 0) & (df['city1'] <= 20)]['city1'].count(), df[(df['city1'] > 20) & (df['city1'] <= 40)]['city1'].count(), df[(df['city1'] > 40) & (df['city1'] <= 60)]['city1'].count(), df[(df['city1'] > 60) & (df['city1'] <= 80)]['city1'].count()], [df[(df['city2'] > 0) & (df['city2'] <= 20)]['city2'].count(), df[(df['city2'] > 20) & (df['city2'] <= 40)]['city2'].count(), df[(df['city2'] > 40) & (df['city2'] <= 60)]['city2'].count(), df[(df['city2'] > 60) & (df['city2'] <= 80)]['city2'].count()], [df[(df['city3'] > 0) & (df['city3'] <= 20)]['city3'].count(),df[(df['city3'] > 20) & (df['city3'] <= 40)]['city3'].count(), df[(df['city3'] > 40) & (df['city3'] <= 60)]['city3'].count(), df[(df['city3'] > 60) & (df['city3'] <= 80)]['city3'].count()]]

#creating a new df with new data

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, index= ['city1', 'city2', 'city3'], columns= ['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80'])

#so the point is to add this "index= ['city1', 'city2', 'city3']," between data and columns when you create a new dataframe
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. Can you please edit you solution so it is more readable?